# The self-kicking system is not functional

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

I've tried to kick myself from a chatroom and got:

[image: Really, you want to kick yourself? I suggest a long walk instead.]

And where's "yes, kick myself" / "no, take a walk" (or something similar) dialogue? That's not functional and should be fixed. And who is "I" by the way?

Comment: I think this fits into the "seriously, you want developers to waste time fixing a joke dialog" category.

Comment: Also fits in the "who cares about a superficial meaningless change that affects so very few people" kind of change

Comment: That's what we have socks for. We can kick them any time, and they won't even squeak.

Comment: @Sha *runs to check whether the socks are alive...*

Comment: The self kicking system is non-existent. What you found was a system which notifies you when you attempt to kick yourself to stop you from doing something by accident that you obviously would not want nor need to do. So, the system you found is working as intended

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The system is working as intended.

Walk-encouragement can be increased on a case-by-case basis as necessary.

Comment: LOL but it prevents fair testing however :D why can I remove myself from room owners in this case, and system doesn't tell me to walk?